# Control a mac with nodejs server

Tags: node.js, macos, sockets, server, dns

I do not really know where to post this question.. I have a nodejs server running on my mac. It listen for message if it receives "shutdown" then I run a command which turns off the mac. This works really great locally in my network. Now how to do the same but  outside my local network. Lets say that I want to turn of my computer outside my house always using my nodejs script? Using dns setup? Thanks in advance!

Comment: you would need to expose your local ip over the internet. there are many ways to do this. for example ngrok (https://ngrok.com/) and serveo (https://serveo.net/). However both of them have their own pros and cons.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tested a lot of things without success for the moment (localtunnel and ngrok). These service works great to expose a web site/app ok but I need to expose a tcp server : https://gist.github.com/MickaelCruzDB/066a7035d75c4fff2d55f8ac65fa8dac

Comment: Can you mention how you tried to use services such as `ngrok`? The origin of the issue could be in how you used and configured the web server.